# Отправка оповещений по времени (время берется из БД)

Tags: php, email, mysql

Доброго времени суток, господа.
Посоветуйте оптимальную реализацию данной задачи:
Есть БД, в которой есть поля `start_time`, `end_time` (тип полей `datetime`) у записей.
Необходимо отправлять уведомления о начале и конце для каждой записи.

К примеру `start_time 01.01.2015 06:00`, значит отправить письмо 1 января в 6 утра о начале.

Как лучше и как часто обращаться в БД за записями?
Ежесекундно мониторить совпадения текущего времени и хотя бы одной записи из БД?

Как оптимально реализовать этот функционал?

Comment: @Salacoste, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

По крону ходите каждые 5 минут, например, зависит от интервала времени в базе, и выбираете те записи, где время совпадает с текущим временем +-2-3 минуты, ну и посылаете, что вам надо. Еще хорошо бы ввести флаг, что сообщение отправлено, чтобы вдруг чего 2 раза не отправлять.

Answer (score 1):

Можно дергать по крону скрипт, который будет собирать письма к отправке с погрешностью в минуту-две. Тогда сам крон будет дергать скрипт каждую минуту. И в худшем случае запоздание составит не более двух минут, если это не критично. Если критично - выставляйте меньший интервал проверки и меньшую погрешность при выборке. Все зависит от допустимой погрешности. Можно дергать кроном скрипт хоть каждую секунду, но зачем?